# How to move previous opened file in NERDTree?

Tags: vim, gvim, macvim, vim-plugins, nerdtree

Does NERDTree have a stack to track opened files? I want to go back to previous file easily(As like ctags does by Ctrl+T).
But I can't find the feature in it's manual. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NERDtree doesn't offer this feature but you can do `:bp` to reopen the previous buffer if it's still in the buffer list or use Vim's jump list (`:h jump`) with `<C-o>` and `<C-i>`. Another solution, if you want to reach those files often, would be to use NERDTree's bookmarking feature.

A [few plugins](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=partner-pub-3005259998294962%3Abvyni59kjr1&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=buffer&sa=Search&siteurl=www.vim.org%2Fscripts%2Findex.php&ref=www.vim.org%2Fscripts%2Fscript_search_results.php%3Fkeywords%3Dbuffer%26script_type%3D%26order_by%3Drating%26direction%3Ddescending%26search%3Dsearch#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=mru) offer some kind of MRU (Most Recently Used) abilities.

You could also learn to navigate between buffers with `:b <Tab>` or `:ls<CR>:b<Space>` or use a neat buffer switching plugin like [CtrlP](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736) or [LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890).

Comment: Well, what solution did you use? I've offered 7 of those.

Comment: :bp and jump list :)

Comment: I think your `few plugins` hyper-link is wrong, though.

Comment: Oops. Answer edited.

Comment: Thanks, helped me too. I just clicked the window then chose the file from the list of buffers in the Buffers-menu, but your answer helped me to remember that it existed ;)